# How to import Firebase inside Xcode

Tags: ios, bash, macos, flutter, xcode10

I have been trying to add firebase to my flutter app but before I do that I must go to Xcode and add something for me to be able to hook firebase for iOS. I have tried the import statement but did not work. This code is in Dart code.

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
override init() {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}

@end

This what I added and did not work and also the import did not work

override init() {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Are you following the setup guide? https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using CocoaPod as dependency manager.

1. Optional (if not already using cocoapods)

   > pod init
2. Add firebase to the podfile and run pod install.

   > pod 'Firebase/Core'
3. Open the workspace not the project. And try importing the framework.

**It should work NOW.**

[Firebase official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should do is put the firebase plist file `GoogleService-Info.plist` inside the `ios/Runner` folder. Add the firebase dependencies to your `pubspec.yaml` file, and run `flutter packages get` This will install the dependencies and run pod install for you. If you have use Firebase in IOS in the past, and you didn't update it maybe would be nice to update the pod version of it with `pod update Firebase`

And remember, do restart completely your app after this.

Also make sure to read this info here https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup